# Avoid spaceless concatenation with JSoup

Tags: java, dom, screen-scraping, jsoup

Suppose I have a div as such:

```
<div>
This is a paragraph
written by someone
on the internet.
</div>
```

The problem is that when JSoup parses this, it puts it all on one line, so that when I call text() it reads as such:

```
This is a paragraphwritten by someoneon the internet.
```

Now, I realize this isn't really a JSoup problem, in that the actual html doesn't contain a space. However, is there any way to use JSoup (perhaps some override or maybe an option I haven't seen) so that as it parses it will add a space between lines? I imagine it must be possible (as I can inspect element in Chrome and unselect word wrap and it gets what I want) but I'm not sure JSoup can do this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following post shows how you get everything including the line break

[Removing HTML entities while preserving line breaks with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348455/removing-html-entities-while-preserving-line-breaks-with-jsoup)

the answer and comment in the following also has another way (read the comment in it)

[Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

and this one has even another way if you check all the answers and the comments

[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: I need to work on my search skills. Thank you. Will accept when time lets me.

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide a full example of your code? What version of jsoup are you using?

In the current version (1.6.1), this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>\n" +
    "This is a paragraph\n" +
    "written by someone\n" +
    "on the internet.\n" +
    "</div>");
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

Produces:

`This is a paragraph written by someone on the internet.`

I.e., `\n` (and `\r\n` etc) are converted to text as spaces.

Happy to fix or improve it, if I can replicate :)

Comment: Actually, Jsoup seems to be perfectly fine, it's the way I was reading in the data (btw, JSoup is pretty awesome). If I'd just done a simple test like the above, I would have known to look elsewhere sooner. However, I am curious now, is it possible to have JSoup not parse the new lines?

Comment: Yes the newlines are retained, and only normalised on .text() output. You can get at them by accessing the TextNode for the text, and hitting .getWholeText() - http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#getWholeText()