# Preserving lines with Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to get some data from html, I have this code:

```
System.out.println("nie jest");
StringBuffer url=new StringBuffer("http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/");
url.append(args[0]);
url.append("/");
url.append(args[1]);
url.append(".html");

//wyciaganie odpowiednich klas z naszego htmla
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
Element lyrics=doc.getElementsByClass("lyrics").first();
Element tracks=doc.getElementsByClass("albumlyrics").first();

//Jso
//lista sciezek
int numberOfTracks=tracks.getElementsByTag("a").size();
```

Everything would be fine, I extracthe data I want, but when I do:

```
lyrics.text()
```

I get the text with no line breaks, so I am wondering how to leave line breaks in displayed text, I read other threads on stackoverflow on this matter but they weren't helpful, I tried to do something like this:

```
TextNode tex=TextNode.createFromEncoded(lyrics.text(), lyrics.baseUri());
```

but I can't get the text I want with line breaks. I looked at previous threads about this like,
[Removing HTML entities while preserving line breaks with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348455/removing-html-entities-while-preserving-line-breaks-with-jsoup)
but I can't get the effect I want. What should I do?

Edit: I got the effect I wanted but I don't think it is very good solution:

```
for (Node nn:listOfNodes)
            {
                String s=Jsoup.parse(nn.toString()).text();
                if ((nn.nodeName()=="#text" || nn.nodeName()=="h3"))
                {
                    buf.append(s+"\n");

                }
            }
```

Anyone got better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the text nodes (the text between `<br />`s) by checking if the node is an instance of `TextNode`. This should work out for you:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
Element lyrics = document.select(".lyrics").first();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(buffer);

for (Node node : lyrics.childNodes()) {
    if (node.nodeName().equals("h3")) {
        writer.println(((Element) node).text());
    } else if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        writer.println(((TextNode) node).text());
    }
}

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

*(please note that comparing the object's internal value should be done by `equals()` method, not `==`; strings are objects, not primitives)*

Oh, I also suggest to read their [privacy policy](http://www.darklyrics.com/privacy.html).

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks, and I will have a look at those policies.