# Keeping line breaks in jsoup to display in android listview

Tags: java, android, listview, jsoup

Heu guys i have an app where i'm parsing an html file using jsoup to display selected texts in a listview in android. However i cant seem to find a way to keep the carriage returns.
Here is what i have attempted :

```
Elements br = doc.select("br");

    for (Element src : br) {
         src.append("\n");
     }
```

To give you an example with a string

```
<div
This is a string <br> another string
/>
```

Is parsed and displays :

```
This is a string another string
```

I have tried using

```
src.append("\\n");
```

Which displays

```
This is a string \n another string
```

I am using an arraylist of strings to store these variables.

Ive been trying to find a solution to this problem with no luck i have attempted solutions from the following threads:

[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text)

[Removing HTML entities while preserving line breaks with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348455/removing-html-entities-while-preserving-line-breaks-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried `src.append("\\n");` it looks like you had just one backslash to much.

Regardless, the first link you posted should point you in the right direction, something like this should work:

```
// parse the doc and select the element containing the text
Elements es = Jsoup
    .parse("<html><body><div>a \ntext<br/>is <b>a</a> text</div></html></body")
    .select("div");

// find <br> tags and replace them (using an arbitrary placeholder '~n~')
es.select("br").append("~n~");
// clean all tags
String clean = Jsoup.clean(es.html(), Whitelist.none());
// replace the placeholder with a real newline
String disp = clean.replaceAll("~n~", "\n");
```

Now `disp` will print:

```
a text 
is a text
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer i actually found a solution, after i appended \n i parsed again and jsoup gets rid of them too.

Comment: So appending something else and then replacing saif thing with \n was the way to go